For a field extension $L/K$, if $[K(\alpha) : K] = 2^n$ for some $n$, is $[F(\alpha) : F] = 2^m$ for some $m$ for all intermediate fields $F$?
Let $L/K$ be a field extension, and $\alpha\in L$. Suppose $[K(\alpha) : K] = 2^n$ for some $n$. Let $F$ be an intermediate field: $K \subset F\subset L$. Is it true that $[F(\alpha) : F] = 2^m$ for some $m$?
Edit: Here are my attempts at solving this problem.

If $f_K$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$, and $f_F$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$, then as $f_K(\alpha)=0$ we have $f_F | f_K$, so $[F(\alpha) : F] =\deg(f_F)\le \deg(f_K)= [K(\alpha) : K]=2^n$. But this doesn't show what we want, which can be reduced to $\deg(f_F) | \deg(f_K)$.
The set of all $\alpha$ such that, for all intermediate fields $F$, there is $m$ s.t. $[F(\alpha) : F]=2^m$, itself forms a field. For example if $\alpha,\beta$ are such elements, then $[F(\alpha,\beta) : F(\beta)]$ and $[F(\beta) : F]$ are powers of two, so $[F(\alpha + \beta) : F]$ which divides $[F(\alpha , \beta) : F] = [F(\alpha , \beta) : F(\beta)][F(\beta) : F]$ is a power of two. Then to disprove the original statement, it suffices to give an example where the set of $\alpha$ s.t. $\exists n,[K(\alpha) : K]=2^n$ is not a field, but I haven't found success so far.


Please check out how to ask a good question. In particular, please what you have tried so far to solve this.

There is a related question here, but without a good answer. I believe there are also exact duplicates but I couldn't find them right now.

Another related question is this one.

@MartinBrandenburg Thank you for the link. I edited the question to add my own attempts. For the first question you linked to, it is related, but it makes the assumption that (in the notation of my question) $K\subset F\subset K(\alpha)$. If this assumption can be made, then $[F(\alpha) : F]$ divides $2^n$ and we get the result. But here there is no such assumption, and $[F : K]$ can be infinite.

This is a very related question, and the counterexample in the top answer answers my question if I replaced my 2 by 3. I intuitively think if my statement is true, its proof would prove it for all primes $p$ replacing 2, but since it is not true for 3, I suspect my statement is false.

$F$ is an intermediate field of which extension? $L/K$, or $K(\alpha)/K$? I can guess (because one makes the problem trivial) but I shouldn't have to.

@ArturoMagidin $F$ is intermediate field of $L/K$. Thanks for the clarification, I edited the question accordingly.

I don't think your counterexample works. The algebraic equation you give for $\alpha$ over $F$ seems to be incorrect. Furthermore, sage tells me that $[F(\alpha):\mathbb Q]=32$, which implies $[F(\alpha):F]=4$.

@anankElpis Thanks, yes I made a basic mistake there

The answer is No. In general we can construct $K \subset F \subset L$ such that $[K(\alpha):K]=n, [F(\alpha):F]=m$ for any $m\le n$.
Let $L$ be the field of polynomial fractions $\mathbb{C}(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, $K$ be $\mathbb{C}(\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_n)$ where $\sigma_i$ are the elementary symmetric polynomials in variables $x_1,\dots,x_n$. Let $\alpha=x_1$. Then the minimal polynomial in $K$ of $\alpha$ divides $\prod_1^n (x-x_i)$. Assume it is $\prod_1^t (x-x_i)$, then $x_1 \dots x_t \in K$. But all elements of $K$ are symmetric in $x_1 ,\dots ,x_n$, so $t=n$. We have shown that $[K(\alpha):K]=n$.
Let $F$ be $K(s_1,\dots,s_m)$, where $s_i$ are the elementary symmetric polynomials in variables $x_1,\dots,x_m$. Then all the elements of $F$ are symmetric in $x_1 ,\dots ,x_m$. By the same way above we can show $[F(\alpha):F]=m$.
